# Add Headline in a foreach Loop when category changes on items from a form submission

Tags: php, foreach

I collect POST variables with Field-Names containing String "object_id" and User_ID (int).
I extract the User ID from the Field Name

In the foreach Loop I need to generate

### Headlines

everytime $object_ds['transaction_type'] changes Value.
but only before the first appearance in the Loop.

I managed to achieve this for the First Line, but I cant figure out how to solve it for $n>1

Any tipps? Thanx

```
  $addonFields = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(preg_grep('/object_id/', array_keys($_POST))));
echo "Anzahl User: ".count($addonFields)."<br>";


$mail_subj_customer = "New! Business Opportunities Pharma & Healthcare";

foreach ($addonFields AS $item=>$value){
echo "Number of Objects: ".count($value)."<br>";


$user_id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $item);  // Extract User ID from $item

$user_ds = holeDS( 'pmcts_users', 'id', $user_id ); // get DataRow from pmcts_users where id=$user_id



$n=0;
foreach ($value AS $values){
$n++;
$object_ds = holeDS( 'pmcts_unternehmen_produkte', 'object_id', $values ); // get Product DataRow
if ($n==1 && $object_ds['transaction_type']=="Company Sale" ){
$current_trans_type = "Company Sale";
echo "<h2>I. Business Opportunities -Company Sales</h2>";
}
if ($n==1 && $object_ds['transaction_type'] == "Asset Sale"){
$current_trans_type = "Asset Sale";
echo "<h2>II. Business Opportunities - Asset Sales</h2>";
}
if ($n==1 && $object_ds['transaction_type'] == "Licensing Opportunity"){
$current_trans_type = "Licensing Opportunity";
echo "<h2>II. Business Opportunities - Licensing</h2>";
}
echo print_r($values)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";

}
}
```

```
It generates Output with a List of Objects like this for every User

Number User: 8
Number Object: 7
<h2>I. Business Opportunities -Company Sales</h2>
22891 - user@customer.com - Company Sale
20071 - user@customer.com - Company Sale
24591 - user@customer.com - Company Sale
<u>(But needs another headline 'Asset Sales' here)</u>
24531 - user@customer.com - Asset Sale
20491 - user@customer.com - Asset Sale
<u>(But needs another headline 'Licesning' here)</u>
24621 - user@customer.com - Licensing Opportunity
24651 - user@customer.com - Licensing Opportunity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider populating arrays first, then iterating through it later. Like:

```
$headlines = array(
        "Company Sale" => "I. Business Opportunities -Company Sales",
        "Asset Sale" => "II. Business Opportunities - Asset Sales",
        "Licensing Opportunity" => "II. Business Opportunities - Licensing" 
);

$allData = array();
foreach ($addonFields AS $item=>$value){
  $user_id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $item);  // Extract User ID from $item
  $user_ds = holeDS( 'pmcts_users', 'id', $user_id ); // get DataRow from pmcts_users where id=$user_id
  foreach ($value AS $values){
     $object_ds = holeDS( 'pmcts_unternehmen_produkte', 'object_id', $values ); 
     if (!isset($allData[$object_ds['transaction_type']])) {
        $allData[$object_ds['transaction_type']] = array();
     }
     $allData[$object_ds['transaction_type']][] = print_r($values, 1)." - $user_ds[email] ;
  }
}
```

Then to display:

```
foreach ($allData as $transaction_type => $users) {
  echo "<h2>" . $headlines[$transaction_type] . "</h2>";
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "<div>" . $user . " - " . $transaction_type . "</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kinglish, that is brilliant and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Kinglish, that is brilliant and it works fine. However It loops through all the users and objects and adds the headline. What would i have to change to loop through all the users and objects and add the headlines on a per user basis.

for example like this:
```
I. Business Oportunities - Company Sale
23456 - user1@company1.com - Company Sale
23458 - user1@company1.com - Company Sale
II. Business Oportunities - Asset Sale
23456 - user1@company1.com - Asset Sale
23458 - user1@company1.com - Asset Sale
II. Business Oportunities - Licensing
23452 - user1@company1.com - Licens ```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved a per User Basis Listing of the Headlines like this:

```
     $addonFields = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(preg_grep('/object_id/', array_keys($_POST))));
    echo "Anzahl User: ".count($addonFields)."<br>";
    
    
    $mail_subj_customer = "New! Business Opportunities Pharma & Healthcare";
    
    $headlines = array(
            "Company Sale" => "I. Business Opportunities - Company Sales",
            "Asset Sale" => "II. Business Opportunities - Asset Sales",
            "Licensing Opportunity" => "III. Business Opportunities - Licensing" 
    );
    
    foreach ($addonFields AS $item=>$value){
    echo "Number of Objects: ".count($value)."<br>";
    
    $count_objects = count($value);
    
    
    $user_id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $item);  // Extract User ID from $item
    
    $user_ds = holeDS( 'pmcts_users', 'id', $user_id ); // get DataRow from pmcts_users where id=$user_id
    
    
    $flag=1;
    $flag2=1;
    $flag3=1;
    $n=0;
    foreach ($value AS $values){
    $n++;
    $object_ds = holeDS( 'pmcts_unternehmen_produkte', 'object_id', $values ); // get Product DataRow
    
    if ($object_ds['transaction_type']=='Company Sale' && $flag==1) {
        echo "<h3>I. Business Opportunities - Company Sales</h3>";
        echo $n.' '.print_r($values, true)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";    
        $flag=0;
    }
    elseif ($object_ds['transaction_type']=='Company Sale' && $flag==0) {
        echo $n.' '.print_r($values, true)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";
            $flag=0;
    }
    
    if ($object_ds['transaction_type']=='Asset Sale' && $flag2==1){
        echo "<h3>II. Business Opportunities - Asset Sales</h3>";
        echo $n.' '.print_r($values, true)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";
        $flag2=0;
    }
    elseif ($object_ds['transaction_type']=='Asset Sale' && $flag2==0) {
        echo $n.' '.print_r($values, true)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";
            $flag2=0;
    }
    
    
    if ($object_ds['transaction_type']=='Licensing Opportunity' && $flag3==1){
        echo "<h3>III. Business Opportunities - Licensing</h3>";
        echo $n.' '.print_r($values, true)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";
        $flag3=0;
    }
    
    elseif ($object_ds['transaction_type']=='Licensing Opportunity' && $flag3==0) {
        echo $n.' '.print_r($values, true)." - $user_ds[email] - $object_ds[transaction_type]<br>";
            $flag3=0;
    }
    
    
    }
    
    
    }
```

Maybe it is helpful for someone with the same issue.